# How do I make my send mails from Outlook available across devices?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I currently have Outlook 2016 installed on my local computer for personal purposes. Outlook 2016 retrieves emails from my Internet Service Provider (which has limited space, IMAP/POP). If I send out emails using my local computer it will not be available on my iPhone since I only see the retrieved emails but not the send emails.

How can I make the sent emails available on my iPhone as well?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, if you are using POP email accounts between devices, it is normal that emails will not be synced between devices. You could try to configure your email account as IMAP account on all your devices. Then sent emails should be able to sync successfully.

Comment: It has been a while, how is everything going?
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.